# VTK BarChart official example failed to compile

Tags: c++, cmake, vtk

I am learning how to use VTK library for plotting in C++. I am following this official [tutorial page](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Cxx/Plotting/BarChart/) for making a BarChart. So I downloaded the example code, downloaded the latest VTK source files, and followed [this official Wiki](https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Configure_and_Build) for compiling VTK using the CMake GUI in Windows 10. Then I placed the built folder (named `VTKb`) into the downloaded example code folder `BarChart`, made the necessary changes in the CMakeLists.txt file as the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12 FATAL_ERROR)

project(BarChart)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH VTKb)

    find_package(VTK COMPONENTS 
      ChartsCore
      CommonColor
      CommonCore
      CommonDataModel
      InteractionStyle
      RenderingContext2D
      RenderingContextOpenGL2
      RenderingCore
      RenderingFreeType
      RenderingGL2PSOpenGL2
      RenderingOpenGL2
      ViewsContext2D
    )
    
    if (NOT VTK_FOUND)
      message(FATAL_ERROR "BarChart: Unable to find the VTK build folder.")
    endif()
    
    # Prevent a "command line is too long" failure in Windows.
    set(CMAKE_NINJA_FORCE_RESPONSE_FILE "ON" CACHE BOOL "Force Ninja to use response files.")
    add_executable(BarChart MACOSX_BUNDLE BarChart.cxx )
      target_link_libraries(BarChart PRIVATE ${VTK_LIBRARIES}
    )
    # vtk_module_autoinit is needed
    vtk_module_autoinit(
      TARGETS BarChart
      MODULES ${VTK_LIBRARIES}
    )
```

The above CMakeLists.txt file is provided in the example code, the only line I added is `set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH VTKb)` to allow CMake to find the VTKb folder. Then I opened a bash terminal and did the following, but encountered an error:

```
    Tong@SimPC MINGW64 /c/github/cpp/jobAnalyzer/BarChart/build (CMake_proj)
    $ cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
    -- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
    -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
    -- Detecting C compile features
    -- Detecting C compile features - done
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe - skipped
    -- Detecting CXX compile features
    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    -- Looking for pthread.h
    -- Looking for pthread.h - found
    -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
    -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
    -- Found Threads: TRUE
    -- Found OpenGL: opengl32  found components: OpenGL
    -- Configuring done
    -- Generating done
    -- Build files have been written to: C:/github/cpp/jobAnalyzer/BarChart/build
    
    Tong@SimPC MINGW64 /c/github/cpp/jobAnalyzer/BarChart/build (CMake_proj)
    $ cmake --build .
    Scanning dependencies of target BarChart
    [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/BarChart.dir/BarChart.cxx.obj
    mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** No rule to make target 'C:/github/cpp/VTKb/lib/libvtkChartsCore-9.2d.dll.a', needed by 'BarChart.exe'.  Stop.
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:94: CMakeFiles/BarChart.dir/all] Error 2
    mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:102: all] Error 2
```

I wonder if someone can point out what this error means, and how to resove it. Thanks.

Comment: Did you build VTK with MInGW?  You may want to use msys2 to install the latest version. [https://www.msys2.org/#installation](https://www.msys2.org/#installation)

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, I built VTK with MinGW through the CMake GUI. I just installed msys2. And I installed (I think) CMake using `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake
`. But when I try `cmake --version` in the MSYS2 terminal, it says `-bash: cmake: command not found`. I am stuck, not sure why `cmake` cannot be found.

Comment: msys2 has cmake in the packaging using pacman: [https://packages.msys2.org/package/cmake?repo=msys&variant=x86_64](https://packages.msys2.org/package/cmake?repo=msys&variant=x86_64) The install command is `pacman -S cmake` from your mingw64 terminal.

Comment: vtk is also a package you can install using pacman: [https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-vtk?repo=ucrt64](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-vtk?repo=ucrt64)